# Persistent Data Container not saving to the block

Tags: bukkit

I am trying to create a custom data to a hopper that is reset survivable. I know that there is a  PersistantDataContainer to store custom metadata. I'm getting a block with an event and then casting it to a hopper instance (of course shocking before casting). When I'm trying to set some data to the instance the data is lost once the method ends and the hopper instance is deleted. Is there any way to save the data to the actual hopper block and get it later event after a reset?

```
Hopper hopper = (Hopper) block.getState();
private final NamespacedKey KEY_SPEED = new NamespacedKey("me.exerosis", "speed");
if (!hopper.getPersistentDataContainer().has(KEY_SPEED, PersistentDataType.INTEGER))
{
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("new");
    hopper.getPersistentDataContainer().set(KEY_SPEED, PersistentDataType.INTEGER, 1);
}
```

Every time this is called on the same block but different event "new" is broadcasted meaning that it is not saving the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [BlockState#update](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/block/BlockState.html#update())

```
hopper.update();
```